# Handling nullable return types in Kotlin data class initialization with known non-null values

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I'm encountering an issue while initializing a Kotlin data class, specifically when dealing with nullable and non-nullable properties. I have two data classes, StartObject and EndObject, and a generic data class DataSet.

Below is the simplified code of my issue.

```
data class EndObject(
  val neverNullDataSet: DataSet<String>,
  val nullableDataSet: DataSet<String>?
) {
  companion object {
    fun from(startObject: StartObject): EndObject{
      return EndObject (
        neverNullDataSet = createDataSet(startObject.neverNullValue),
//above results in error because createDataSet returns DataSet<String>?, even though it can't be null
        nullableDataSet = createDataSet(startObject.nullableValue) 
//above is ok, as expected
       )
    }
    fun createDataSet(value: String?): DataSet<String>? {
       return if (value == null) null
       else DataSet(value)
    }
  }
}

data class StartObject(
  val neverNullValue: String,
  val nullableValue: String?
)

data class DataSet<String>( 
  val importantValue: String // Will never be null since it won't be created if importantValue is missing
)
```

The issue arises when calling the createDataSet function within the companion object constructor. The createDataSet function returns a nullable DataSet?, but the neverNullDataSet property in EndObject expects a non-nullable DataSet. This results in a compilation error.

While I understand that the createDataSet function may return null in certain cases, I know that it won't return null when called with startObject.neverNullValue. In other words, the returned value will always be non-null, even though the return type allows nullability.

Is there a way to handle this situation where the return type of createDataSet is nullable, but it is known that it won't be null in certain scenarios? I want to avoid having to make the neverNullDataSet property nullable in the EndObject class. I'm aware of the null safety operator(!!), but I would prefer to make the compiler to be dynamically aware of the neverNullDataSet to never be nullable.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Create an overload of `createDataSet` that takes a non-nullable String and returns a non-nullable DataSet.

Comment: As a more general thing, you might want to look into *Kotlin Contacts* which were introduced as experimental uh, quite a while ago https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew13.html#contracts Not sure how far along that is now (stdlib uses them apparently, e.g. for smart casting) but that allows you to declare some specific rules to help the compiler understand more about how your code is supposed to work, and what consequences are implied by doing this thing or that thing. But for this specific case, the overload approach is definitely simpler (and more standard)!

Comment: I'd change `createDataSet()` to both accept and return non-nullable values, and then avoid calling it on nulls. One easy way to do that would be to make it an extension method on String, and call it with `.?`.

Comment: The !! operator is the appropriate way to deal with cases where the compiler can't prove a value is nonnull.